# Calculation of PI() and 3.14159265358979 in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel while Calculating `=SIN(PI())` formula it returns `1.22515E-16`.If the  `PI()` `Value(3.14159265358979)` is directly given like =SIN(3.14159265358979), it returns `3.23114E-15`.

Please anyone can share your opinion about how the excel calculates differently, when 'PI' and 3.14159265358979 are passed as parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Let's have the following example:

[image]

`A2` is formula `=PI()`.

`A3` is value `3.14159265358979`.

`A5` is value copied from `A2` and then paste-special: Values only.

Formula in column `B` is `=SIN(A2)` ... `=SIN(A5)`.

So what is happening here?

While `Microsoft` justifies the truncating values to 15 digits with using double floating point precision according [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats), this is not the whole truth. According IEEE 754 the possible count of decimal digits is not exactly 15 but 15.95 in average. So there are more digits possible in some cases. And if so, `Excel` stores up to 17 digits in its files although it shows only 15 digits in its sheet views and also only 15 digits can be input in its sheet views.

So `=PI()` will result in `3.1415926535897931` exactly and this value will also be stored. But manual input can only be `3.14159265358979`. But if you copy/paste-special:Values the result of `=PI()`, then also `3.1415926535897931` will be stored although only `3.14159265358979` is shown.

Since `*.xlsx` files are simply `ZIP` archives, we can unzip them and look at `/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml`. There we will find:

```
<row r="2" spans="1:2" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
 <c r="A2" s="1">
  <f>PI()</f>
  <v>3.1415926535897931</v>
 </c>
 <c r="B2">
  <f>SIN(A2)</f>
  <v>1.22514845490862E-16</v>
 </c>
</row>
<row r="3" spans="1:2" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
 <c r="A3" s="1">
  <v>3.14159265358979</v>
 </c>
 <c r="B3">
  <f>SIN(A3)</f>
  <v>3.2311393144413003E-15</v>
 </c>
</row>
<row r="5" spans="1:2" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
 <c r="A5" s="1">
  <v>3.1415926535897931</v>
 </c>
 <c r="B5">
  <f>SIN(A5)</f>
  <v>1.22514845490862E-16</v>
 </c>
</row>
```

q.e.d.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing this is because of a rounding error.

`Sin(PI())` is technically 0, as detailed in [the Sin function documentation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/SIN-function-cf0e3432-8b9e-483c-bc55-a76651c95602). However, excel returns `1.22515E-16` or `0.0000000000000001225148455`
(i.e. approximately `0`)

`3.14159265358979` is a approximation of `PI()`, so it returns a different number that it also approximately `0`. If you try `3.1415926535897`, `3.141592653589` etc, you will get a different number each time.

This is likely related to working with [floats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic), but I don't know enough about Excel and how it stores data to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

The `SIN()` function accepts the parameter in `radians`.

To convert an angle to radians, the value must be multiplied by `PI()/180`.

If you use `=SIN(PI())`, the PI is considered as a radian which is equal to `RADIANS(180)`. Both `=SIN(PI())` and `=SIN(RADIANS(180))` returns the same result `0`.

`=SIN(3.14159265358979)` is not actually equal to `=SIN(PI())` because the PI in this context is different. And hence the different result.

The bottom line is to always use radians as a parameter for trigonometric functions.

Comment: With `=SIN(3.14159265358979)`, my understanding is that the function will treat the number as radians. To handle it as degrees, `=SIN(DEGREES(3.14159265358979))` would be required.

Comment: confirmed by calculating elsewhere; In degrees, `Sin(3.14159265358979)` is around `0.0548`

Comment: Thanks for your update.

Radians(180) also returns the PI() value (3.14159265358979) only. So how can I differentiate this?

Comment: @ElakkiyaLucky you need to always use radians as a parameter for SIN function